# Using jquery dotdotdot in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to use jQuery plugin in my project.
I am using Ionic3

I have already installed jquery , and also downloaded the plugin

`npm install jquery --save`
`typings install dt~jquery --global --save`

from the plugin docs: I added the script tags in `index.html`

```
<head>
 ////
 <script src="assets/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/jquery.dotdotdot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>// path assets inside www folder where I'd put the file .js
////
</head>
```

.html: (page)

```
////
<div id="wrapper">
 <p>"{{summary}}"</p>
</div>
```

.ts:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

///
ngOnInit(){
    $("#wrapper").dotdotdot({
        ellipsis : '... ',
        wrap : 'word',
        fallbackToLetter: true,
        height: null
    });
}
```

I get error:
`Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery__(...).dotdotdot is not a function`

I tried adding both `.js` and `.min.js` files , but I get the same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40355691/4826457

Comment: Please see this.Maybe helped to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159347/ionic2-how-to-use-jquery-plugin-in-page

Comment: @suraj hmm.. still no luck... jquery is working fine `$('#wrapper').width()`

Answer (score 0):

You install the same way as the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2/40355691#40355691).

Install library [dotdotdot.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotdotdot)

```
npm install dotdotdot --save
```

Install [@types package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dotdotdot)

```
npm install --save-dev @types/dotdotdot
```

Then do

```
 import * as $ from "dotdotdot";
```

Comment: oh and not to forget to say... the page that I am trying to run jquery, is a subcomponent

Comment: try importing from `dotdotdot`

Comment: `"dotdotdot"` is underlined red... node_module/@types/dotdotdot/index.d.ts is not a module

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/dotdotdot/dotdotdot-tests.ts

Comment: can you please elaborate more about the link... I have the file `index.d.ts` in the node_module

Comment: the link is a test file to try the index.d.ts,, see if you can import the same way..

Comment: using `///<reference types="jquery" />` I get error: `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery___default(...)(...).dotdotdot is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

the proper usage of jquery inside ionic is

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

you can try the same way also in dotdotdot

```
import dot from "dotdotdot";
```

Comment: have you tried it already , and its working??... cuz I remember doing all the possible solutions but none worked