# Ionic2 Jquery is not defined

Tags: ionic2, slick.js

I have imported following line in `.ts` file

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

Before that I have installed it with

```
npm install jquery --save
```

But it's returning  error

> jQuery is not defined

Comment: It isn't recomended to use jquery with Ionic, but if you have not other way, It seems that they have solved it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159347/ionic2-how-to-use-jquery-plugin-in-page

Comment: i have tried following link,But it returns Cannot find module 'jquery'. before that i have installed the jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct way to import this as i am using this is.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

then to use this

```
public test(){
$('#test').height('100px');
}
```

html

```
 <button id=test ion-button (tap)="test()" block>TEST</button>
```

Comment: isn't working for me. If try to define a <script> block im my template $ is still undefined. jQuery is installed. But where do I have to import the $?

Comment: I have the same problem, how have you fixed it?

Comment: sorry for very late reply .  what ionic version your currently working on ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Add this

> "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

inside style[] in angular.json